# Remove column from Group By

Tags: sql, t-sql

The query I'm attempting to create:

> Find the recipe(s) that use the most cloves of Garlic. (1 column, 1 row)

My issue is that I have to include `Recipes.RecipeTitle` in my `Group By` clause or else I get an error. And whenever I include it in `Group By`, my query returns 4 results instead of 1 (Roast Beef).

Can someone help explain how to rewrite this so that I possibly won't need the `Group By` clause.

```
select distinct 
    Recipes.RecipeTitle
from 
    Recipes
inner join 
    Recipe_Ingredients on Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
inner join 
    Ingredients on Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID = Ingredients.IngredientID
group by 
    Recipe_Ingredients.Amount, Recipes.RecipeTitle
having 
    Recipe_Ingredients.Amount = max(Recipe_Ingredients.Amount)
    and Recipes.RecipeTitle IN (select Recipes.RecipeTitle
                                from Recipes
                                inner join Recipe_Ingredients on Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
                                inner join Ingredients on Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID = Ingredients.IngredientID
                                group by Recipes.RecipeTitle, Ingredients.IngredientName
                                having Ingredients.IngredientName in ('garlic'));
```

Database diagram:

[image]

[Also here is a DB Fiddle I created](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6da5ce3483176069239a515758ac6af1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter for the garlic *before* aggregating.  After all, you want recipes that have some amount of garlic in them.

Second, this needs to assume that the measurements for garlic are all the same, so you can just use the `amount` as a measure.

Then, one method is to use `select top (1)` or `select top (1) with ties` to get the results.  The difference is that `select top (1)` always returns exactly one row even when multiple recipes have the same maximum amount of garlic.

So:

```
select top (1) with ties r.RecipeTitle
from Recipes r join
     Recipe_Ingredients ri
     on r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID join
     Ingredients i
     on ri.IngredientID = i.IngredientID
where i.IngredientName = 'garlic'
group by r.RecipeID, r.RecipeTitle
order by sum(amount) desc;
```

It is possible to measure garlic in different units -- for instance, "heads" versus "cloves", so you might need to take the measurement unit into account:

```
select top (1) with ties r.RecipeTitle
from Recipes r join
     Recipe_Ingredients ri
     on r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID join
     Ingredients i
     on ri.IngredientID = i.IngredientID join
     Measurements m
     on ri.measurementAmountID = m.measurementAmountID
where i.IngredientName = 'garlic' and
      i.MeasurementDescription = 'clove'
group by r.RecipeID, r.RecipeTitle
order by sum(amount) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate, sort and limit:

```
select top (1) with ties r.RecipeTitle
from Recipes r
inner join Recipe_Ingredients ri on r.RecipeID = ri.RecipeID
inner join Ingredients i on ri.IngredientID = i.IngredientI
group by r.RecipeID, r.RecipeTitle
order by sum(case when i.IngredientName = 'garlic' then 1 else 0 end) desc
```

Notes:

- I used `with ties` so if there are top ties, the query returns them
- table aliases make the query shorter to write